# How to deal with "HelperDb.ExecuteSql(@"..SomeQuery.sql")" in unit testing? C# .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm new to Unit Testing, and I know that a test depending upon an external resource (like a file or database) is not a unit test, it's an integration test instead.

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext context)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("../database_scripts/test_scripts/some_query.sql"))
        {
            HelperDb.ExecuteSql("../database_scripts/test_scripts/some_query.sql");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't have any database installed on the server and don't want even to install it, and wanna test using RhinoMocks. How can I perform this test? Any help or comments are warmely welcome :)

Comment: So you want to execute a SQL script as part of your test suite, but you don't want to use a database? What are you expecting?

Comment: Steven, thanks for your nice response. Actually I don't want to execute SQL script(s) at all as I don't have any database installed. However, I'm looking forward for some solution other than using database or executing any query against the database.

Comment: Why don't you remove that code from your Init method?

Comment: I'm looking forward to by-pass the execution of SQL script(s).

Comment: Don't call `HelperDb.ExecuteSql` from within your tests.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm trying to perform unit testing and my unit test is using object of another class, and that class depends upon HelperDb class. I want to get rid of these dependencies. I'm getting following error:

Test method threw an exception: Can't open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed...

As I already have mentioned that I don't have any database installed, so how can I perform the test without database? I mean how to mock the database, what is the optimum solution or best practice for this?